# iOS Designable always failing, no warning

Tags: ios, swift

So I created this simple subclass to have design-time data for cells:

```
@IBDesignable
class UIPrototypeLabel: UILabel {

    @IBInspectable var designTimeText: String? {
        didSet {
            #if TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER
                self.text = designTimeText
            #endif
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't even set any label to this class yet, and the IB build is already failing **with no warnings**.

After I set a `UILabel` with it's class as `UIPrototypeLabel` and set the `Design Time Text` attribute in **Attribute Inspector**, it creates the **User Defined Runtime Attributes** with the right key and value, but I get `ignoring user defined runtime attribute for key path designTimeText on instance UILabel`

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. I'm on Xcode 3.6.2

Comment: It solved by randomly Cleaning and Building, but not just 1 call; I did like random patterns like: Clean, Clean, Build, Clean, Build, Build, Build, Clean Build... or something like that and eventually it fixed itself... I was like what??